# The suitcase lock

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, np

I guess there is no polynomial algorithm for opening a code lock with n dials on a suitcase.
However, to verify an existing solution is easy, it consists simply of opening the suitcase.
So the problem is in NP, but not in P.

Obviously I am mistaken. Where am I wrong?

Comment: By using suitcase dial-based locks, you are just adding unnecessary decoration to the problem of "I am thinking of a number between 1 and n... guess the number".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming theory, algorithms, or algorithmic problem solving. Possible match for programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Where you are mistaken is in assuming that "find the solution" and "verify a given solution" are the same problem. They are not.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru- No SIR,sorry to disagree,but, it is well fitted under algorithms tag and several other similar questions have been answered on StackOverflow here.

Comment: He's not saying they're the same problem. No polynomial time solution implies that the problem is not in `P`. Polynomial time verification implies that the problem is in `NP`. The problem is that this implies that `P != NP`.

Comment: @indiv: you are almost right, except the number is between 1 and 10^n. I like the locks though because they make the digits of the number to be guessed more vivid.

Comment: What is missing from the model is a computational model describing the verification process.  The verification is strictly a physical model rather than a computational one.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start from the end - you haven't just proven P!=NP in a 2-line Stack Overflow question.

The problem is your suitcase problem isn't well defined. Turing machines can't open suitcases, you need to model a suitcase somehow.

Since complexity depends on the *input's length*, without knowing how you model a suitcase, there's really no way of discussing complexities.

For example, if you follow @indiv's comment's logic, your suitcase model can be the combination that opens the lock. In that case, you can solve it in constant time:

```
def figure_suitcase_code(code):
    return code
```

You haven't defined your problem properly - you can't say anything about the complexity.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with zmbd's answer.

I would like to expand it a little bit. Deterministic problems shouldn't have hidden numbers to be guessed; the entire problem to be solved should be clear. Deterministic problems are more like chess than like poker: the entire problem statement should be accessible to the algorithm.

However, Computer Science often studies complexity classes with "oracles". An oracle is more or less a black box that has some **hidden** from the algorithm criteria for answering "yes/no" questions. Your suitcase problem essentially includes an oracle that allows you to open the suitcase if and only if the lock coincide with the **hidden number**. With the help of that oracle your implied question can be made rigorous:

*Given an oracle A that has a hidden combination of locks the problem of opening the suitcase is clearly in NP^A, but not in P^A. Does that prove that P != NP?*

The answer to the above question is no: it turns out that there exists an oracle A for which P^A != NP^A, and also exists an oracle B for which P^B == NP^B. Therefore your perfectly correct observation that opening the suitcase is in NP *relative to the hidden number oracle*, but not in P *relative to the same hidden number oracle* does not prove that P != NP.

Here's the original paper about that:

T. P. Baker, J. Gill, and R. Solovay, "Relativizations of the P =? NP Question"